# GetAsyncKeyState() - outside program interferes with it

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, mfc

I wrote a small program that uses GetAsyncKeyState() and it works fine on its own.

The problem is that when I run a certain outside app (not mine) my GetAsyncKeyState() completely stops receiving input. I would like to be able to run both apps.

Is there something I can do to force my program to receive keyboard input again ? What could be causing this problem ?

Thanks !

**More details****

I'm working with MFC and process a WM_TIMER message which leads to capturing keyboard input. I made the input configurable and then I call

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(chVirtualKey) < 0) { //stuff happens }
```

**UPDATE****
I made another test app (non MFC) setting up a hook with my limited knowledge about them:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, &LowLevelKeyboardProc, hInstance, NULL);
```

Then processing it:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* p = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;

        if (p->vkCode == VK_SPACE) // spacebar key
        {
             SetCursorPos(400, 400); //just to test
        }
     }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This hook works but only while the other app is not running so I'm still stuck...

Comment: So you're losing keyboard input even when your app has focus?

Comment: What do you mean it stops receiving input? `GetAsyncKeyState` doesn't "receive input" itself. When are you calling it? Are you polling? Calling in response to a message? Show some source code...

Comment: `Get(Async)KeyState()` relies on keyboard data that is cached locally in the calling thread. The only way that an outside process can interfere with that is if it is either using [`BlockInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290.aspx), or is using a hook to intercept and discard/modify keyboard messages before they reach your thread's message queue.

Comment: @Remy: The hook intercepting the keyb msg sounds most likely to me. Is there a way to re-intercept the msg without abandoning the use of GetAsyncKeystate() ? (I'm a novice programmer)
Thank you !

Comment: Can I suggest an experiment: Create a simple dialog based app, that handles `WM_TIMER` with `GetAsyncKeyState` and see if that is also 'broken' when the other app is running. This will tell you if it's the other app's fault entirely or if your app is also contributing in some way.

Comment: @user1793036: I made a bare bones app like you described and yes it's still broken ->only<- while the other app is running..

Comment: Other than hooking the keyboard yourself (look at `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()`), or prompting the user not to run the other app, there is probably nothing else you can do. Maybe contact the owner of the other app and complain that it is interfering with your app.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Is there a particular hook you were thinking of ? I'll try to implement RegisterRawInputDevices() next. Thanks !

Comment: @Soran: There are only two keyboard hooks available with `SetWindowsHookEx()` - `WH_KEYBOARD` and `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. Try them both. But Raw Input would be better since the data comes directly from the keyboard and not a group of system queues. I do not know if it is affected by `BlockInput()`, though.

Comment: @Soran: I tested `BlockInput()` and it does block Raw Input events, which makes sense as it is blocking physical input. On the other hand, it also appears that only admin processes can call `BlockInput()`. Is the other app running as an admin? If not, then it has to be blocking keyboard input though other means, probably through `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I tried RegisterRawInputDevices() with the same result as the other methods...

"Process Explorer v16.01" wasn't able to say if it runs as Admin but the UAC column of Taskmanager confirmed that it is running in an elevated state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to support for the other app my problem was resolved. 
All I had to do was have my app run in admin mode.

Thanks for everybody's help ! I did learn some new tricks with Hooks.